# How can I select the data in jQuery table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, thymeleaf

I get a jQuery table and using Thymeleaf to call data from database. I want to choose the data when I click that button. After I filter out some data with my controller, I check the console.log of the data row, which is undefined.

Here is my javascript

```
function showApplication(){

    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("#no").html();

    console.log(col1);
    }
```

Here is the html of my table

```
<table id="coursetable" class="coursetable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th>Application No.</th>
            <th>Applicant Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Course Code</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Course Date</th>
            <th>Course Time</th>
            <th>Cancel Application <span>*</span></th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  th:each="app : ${inclass}">
            <td id="no" name="no" th:text="${app.applicationNo}"></td>
            <td th:text="${app.appApplicantNameEng}"></td>
            <td th:text="${app.appStatus}"></td>
            <td th:text="${app.classId.courseId.courseCode}"></td>
            <td th:text="${app.classId.courseId.courseTitleEng1}"></td>
            <td th:text="${app.classId.classDate}"></td>
            <td th:text="${app.classId.startTime}+ ' - ' + ${app.classId.endTime}" ></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="btn_show" value="Cancel Application" class="showapplicationbutton" onclick="showApplication();"></input</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.